# installing a 3rd party module on a puppet agent

Tags: puppet

We have a puppetmaster and an agent machine I'm configuring from it, via the `puppet agent -t` command.

On this agent machine (an Ubuntu box) I need the `bc` (base calculator) command installed when it's built.  Right now that's not the case.

There appears to be a module for it on the forge (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/rfletcher/bc/readme) but I'm fairly new to puppet and am not sure how to set things up so that when the Ubuntu box is spun up this module is installed?

I'm going over the agent [docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/agent_master_basic.html) but am still learning about how agents communicate with puppetmasters.  I'm hoping for a nudge on what to do to make sure this command is installed on my agent when all is said and done (stick something in a manifest somewhere most likely?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asking how to use forge modules in puppet. My first suggestion is, read the relative documents as more as possible, all in [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com)

If you need get quick start, here are something you can try.

```
login puppet master
cd to puppet module folder
puppet module install rfletcher-bc
mv rfletcher-bc bc
```

then find the node pp file (normally it should be init.pp) to add below line:

```
include bc
```

I didn't have your environment, and not sure which pp file will be targeted.